# I need to compare two lines in BASh script, ignoring whitespaces at the beginning and end, ignoring EOL / EOF

Tags: bash

Currently i am using

$STR1 != $STR2

Each STR has multiple lines inside. 
The two lines are read from two different files and sometimes it fails on EOL/EOF/Dot at the end of line.

I need to eliminate the EOL/EOF/Dot-at-the-end-of-line (and only at the end).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Consider in the future including sample data that includes all the cases you want to compare correctly (and, optionally, your existing code); this would help make your question a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (An EOL and an EOF are very different things; I'd be surprised if your data had a literal ASCII EOF marker -- haven't seen them in wide use anywhere since the 80s/90s). Anyhow, including a reproducer in the question would eliminate any places where that question could be read as unclear by providing a definitive test for whether an answer is correct.

Comment: thanks :-) Will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique to compare two strings which are allowed to differ in a limited set of ways is to normalize them -- to perform a transform which eliminates those differences. If you want to normalize for case, for instance, an easy transform is to change both sides to all-uppercase or all-lowercase; to normalize for leading whitespace, one can simply eliminate it.

---

```
normalize() {
  s=${1//$'\r\n'/$'\n'} # change CRLFs to LFs
  s=${1%$'\n'}          # eliminate any trailing LF

  # run other transforms (removing leading whitespace, trailing dots) line-by-line
  sed -E \
      -e 's/^[[:space:]]+//' \
      -e 's/[.]$//' \
      <<<"$s"
}

# compare normalized strings    
if [[ "$(normalize "$STR1")" = "$(normalize "$STR2")" ]]; then
  echo "Strings are identical after normalization"
else
  echo "Strings differ after normalization"
fi
```

Notes:

- `$''` allows backslash-escapes to be used to express literals; thus, `$'\r\n'` is a literal CRLF.
- `${var//foo/bar}` expands `$var` with all instances of `foo` replaced with `bar`.
- While using `[[ ]]` makes most quotes unnecessary, on a comparison quoting the right-hand side ensures that it is treated as a literal string rather than a glob expression.
- `sed -E` is an equivalent to the GNUism `sed -r` (enabling ERE syntax) that additionally works with modern BSD `sed`, including that on MacOS X.